# Git merge branch master?

Tags: github, merge, branch

I am not sure what github is telling me to do here. I only have one branch, which is master.

[screenshot][1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pidwfm5q7r8l403/Screenshot%202014-08-15%2018.23.00.png)

Answer (score 0):

Master is default branch. Your main branch. It automatically comes when you open a repository. If you open another branch, it means that you have master and one more.